# Getting 5 second loading spinner for form submit button in bootstrap 4 to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and trying to prompt the user for a string input, then get them to hit a submit button, which will turn into a greyed out spinner button ([see this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/#buttons)) indicating the data is being loaded, and then after 5 seconds, the form is submitted, and then the user is directed to the same page with the results in the URL via the GET method: page.com/creation?name="test"

I can't for the life of me figure out how to handle the javascript to do this. I'm able to get the spinner working after some text is submitted though.

Can you help me with the javascript to only make it do the spinning for 5 seconds, and then submit the form.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
      // disable button
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      // add spinner to button
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loading...`
      );
    });
});
</script>


<div class="form-group">
<div style="margin:3em;">
  <form action="/creation" id="testForm" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    <button type="submit" id="btnFetch" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `.delay()` method? https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Hi @glend, I tried using the `delay` method with `$('#btnFetch').submit();` but after more than an hour of fiddling with it, I couldn't get it to work...

Comment: You can try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075115/set-a-delay-time-for-spinner-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a timeOut function to submit form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
      // disable button
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      // add spinner to button
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loading...`
      );

setTimeout(function(){
    /*submit the form after 5 secs*/
    document.getElementByID('testForm').submit();
},5000)

    });
});
</script>
```

or in jQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){
        /*submit the form after 5 secs*/
        $('#testForm').submit();
    },5000)
```